# Magento error while installation

Tags: magento2

Magento Installer

```
Readiness Check
Add a Database
Web Configuration
Customize Your Store
Create Admin Account
Install
```

Step 6: Install

```
Installing... 50%
Installation is incomplete.
Check the console log for errors before trying again.
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Security':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Vault':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Robots':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_Integration':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':

Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Security':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Vault':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Robots':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_Integration':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Running schema recurring...

DDL cache cleared successfully

Installing user configuration...


Module 'Magento_Theme':
Installing data...
Enabling caches:
Current status:
Array ( [config] => 1 [layout] => 1 [block_html] => 1 [collections] => 1 [reflection] => 1 [db_ddl] => 1 [eav] => 1 [customer_notification] => 1 [full_page] => 1 [config_integration] => 1 [config_integration_api] => 1 [translate] => 1 [config_webservice] => 1 )

Installing data...
Data install/update:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':
Installing data...
[ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AD' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #5 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #6 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #7 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1938): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #8 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\module-directory\Setup\InstallData.php(294): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->insertArray('directory_count...', Array, Array) #9 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(844): Magento\Directory\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #10 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(796): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') #11 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() #12 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #13 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #14 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #16 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #17 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #18 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #19 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #20 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #21 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #22 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #23 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #24 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\index.php(37): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #25 {main} Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AD' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `directory_country` (`country_id`,`iso2_code`,`iso3_code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) in C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:235 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #4 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #5 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #6 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1938): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `di...', Array) #7 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\magento\module-directory\Setup\InstallData.php(294): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->insertArray('directory_count...', Array, Array) #8 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(844): Magento\Directory\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #9 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(796): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') #10 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() #11 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #12 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #13 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #14 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #15 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #16 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #17 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #18 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #19 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #20 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #21 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #22 C:\wamp\www\start\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #23 C:\wamp\www\start\setup\index.php(37): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #24 {main}
```

Comment: please make sure that Database that you are trying to install magento is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the `directory_country` table in the database:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `directory_country`;
```

and repeat installation. The main issue could be not a clean database which you are using during install.

***Update:***

In case of reference error during truncating a table you can disable foreign key check, truncate a table and enable foreign key check again:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `directory_country`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

The root of the problem is a not empty database which you are using for the new Magento install.

Comment: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`start`.`weee_tax`, CONSTRAINT `WEEE_TAX_COUNTRY_DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_COUNTRY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `start`.`directory_country` (`country_id`))

Comment: @user10056419 You can clean entire database or, better way, disable foreign key check, truncate table, enable foreign key check:
```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `directory_country`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```